# Magento Migration Unable to serialize value from sales_flat_order_item

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, unserialize

I'm getting error while Migrating data from **1.9.3.3** to **2.2.6** CE.

Error I'm getting is like below:

> Could not unserialize data of sales_flat_order_item.product_options
>   with record id 7.

I've checked that field there is broken value like : **b:0;**

**Rather than this other fields have complete serialize data.**

**Note : I've also more fields with universalize value.**

Thanks If you help me with this.

Comment: Can you try dropping your target database and recreating it and restarting your migration? (The M2 database)

Comment: Have you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after trying to fix the serialized string I ended up understanding that it was impossible. I tried everything from this great [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/how-to-repair-a-serialized-string-which-has-been-corrupted-by-an-incorrect-byte), but either the proposed solution wouldn't work either some information would get losted when fixing the string.

The simplest solution I found was to add a try and catch at the line 81 of this file: src/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/SerializeToJson/SalesOrderItem.php

Just add a try and catch here:

```
$optionValue = $option['option_value'] ? unserialize($option['option_value']) :
                            $option['option_value'];
```

- That would prevent the issue from stopping the migration
- The custom options wrongly generated in Magento 1 wouldn't be imported (but they were already wrong in magento 1)

More detailed information you can find it [here](https://www.catgento.com/2020/04/16/magento-2-migration-errors-unserialize/?preview=true).